# How can I measure an AC magnetic field using a linear Hall effect sensor with an Arduino?

Tags: arduino, ac, electromagnetic, hall-effect, field-strength

I have a SS49E Hall effect sensor. I want to measure the magnetic field in gauss using an Arduino analog output. I have code for analog applications but is this appropriate just for the DC magnetic field measurement? I am using a voltage transformer whose turn ratio is 100 V and 34,5 kV primary and secondary windings respectively. The transformer provides AC current at 50 Hz so there is AC magnetic field in the test setup.

Can I measure the AC magnetic field at a constant frequency of 50 Hz with the Arduino, or is there another microconroller for this measurement?

Comment: You can but do some research at Allegro and use those https://www.allegromicro.com/en/Design-Center/Technical-Documents/Hall-Effect-Sensor-IC-Publications/Allegro-Hall-Effect-Sensor-ICs.aspx

Comment: @Fatih: I think you're going to really struggle with this. You can't measure with a microcontroller's output and the Arduino series don't have one anyway, as far as I know. You would need an analog input instead (which they do have). Since the field is alternating at 50 Hz you will have to sample at a much higher rate than that to get meaningful results. You will also need to be able to handle reversal of polarity.

Comment: Yes you are right, i am wrong but my application include just analog input. I write wrong the question.

Answer (score 1):

As an indicator of field strength the SS49E will be just fine, but if you want to calibrate this as a gauss meter then it may be more problematic. I assume you incorrectly used analog output where you meant analog input in your question.

The [SS49E](https://sensing.honeywell.com/index.php?ci_id=50359) outputs about half supply voltage (you are likely to see 2.5 +/- 0.1 commonly among devices) with zero gauss detected. You will need to provide an offset and gain facility to get any reasonable calibration.

A more suitable (though hard to get at times) linear Hall Effect device would be the [WSH315](http://www.winson.com.tw/Data%20Sheet/WSH315.pdf) which has flexible VDD offset adjustment which can be made to track your A/D reference.

Comment: Thanks Jack, I realized i write wrong in the question about analog application. So it is not output but it is a analog input on the board and arduino code.

Comment: I calibrated SS49E with a gauss meter. But i can not measure ac magnetic field strength in a gauss level.

Answer (score 0):

Sampling rate and bandwidth wise you should be good if there are no high order harmonics in the current. If there are harmonics >10kHz and they are significant for your measurement, then I suggest increasing your ADC sampling rate. Apart from that, I am not sure how you would calibrate your readings and ensure repeatability.